# $\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{1/n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis

I think this limit is going to go to 1 by the squeeze theorem. Clearly, $1\leq  n^{1/n^2}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now, I'll show that $ n^{1/n^2}\leq 1+\frac{1}{n}$ if and only if $n\leq \left[1+\frac{1}{n}\right]^{n^2}$ if and only if $1\leq \frac{(n+1)^{n^2}}{n^{n^2-1}}$. If $n=1$, then clearly, $1\leq 2$. Now, if $1\leq \frac{(m+1)^{m^2}}{m^{m^2-1}}$ is true and we can show that $1\leq \frac{(m+2)^{m^2+2m+1}}{(m+1)^{m^2+2m}}$ then by induction, we'll be finished. Notice that $(m+2)\left(\frac{m+2}{m+1}\right)^{m^2+2m}\geq (m+2)\left(\frac{m+2}{m+2}\right)^{m^2+2m}\geq 1$. However, there seems something wrong with this but I'm not quite sure what it is. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to apply the sleaky AM-GM inequality...:

$\sqrt[n^2]{n} = \sqrt[n^2]{1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdots 1\cdot \sqrt{n}\cdot \sqrt{n}} \leq \dfrac{(n^2-2)\cdot 1+ 2\sqrt{n}}{n^2} = 1+\dfrac{2\sqrt{n}-2}{n^2} < 1+\dfrac{1}{n}$. This sounds better than yours....

Comment: Ahh, this is much better. Thanks!

Comment: Sure is. The AM-GM is powerful....

Answer (score 0):

you can instead apply the Bernoulli inequality $(1+\alpha)^n>1+n\alpha$ (for $\alpha>-1,n>1$).
in your case, you get
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}>1+n^2\cdot\frac{1}{n}=1+n>n.$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x)=x^{1/x^{2}}$ so that $\ln f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x^{2}}$. Either by L'Hospital's Rule or by observing that this quotient is $\leq 1/x$ for $x$ large enough, you find the limit is zero. Then $f(x)$ itself has limit equal to $1$.